# Reference local build of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc in AspNetCore application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

How can I reference a local build of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` in my Asp.Net Core application?  I'm trying to debug something in the framework.  I've pulled down the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc) and have it compiled, but I can't get my application to see the location to pick-up the code.

My global.json file:

```
{
  "projects": [
    "src",
    "test",
    "c:/source/repos/mvc/src"
  ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
}
```

Snippet of my package.json file.  The version is the same version as the DLL that is built:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.2.0-preview1",
      "type": "build"
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be sure it will use the project reference instead of the nuget reference you can specify the dependency target:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": {
  "version": "1.2.0-preview1",
  "type": "build",
  "target" : "project" //this will make sure it only looks for a project
},
```

Also make sure you run `dotnet restore` before you build the project.